# Hibernate: Determine whether an instance is new in beforeCommit (after save, instance.id != null)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails

Is there a way to determine if a domain instance is new in a beforeCommit callback?

Context: A grails application (v. 2.2.1), which uses spring and hibernate underneath.

Use-case:
We need to send a message to an external system whenever an instance of a given type (Parent) or its children change "in a significant way", e.g. a Parent property changes, Parent gets an "approved" new child etc. **There can be many events that would trigger a message for a Parent within the same transaction**, and we need to send **only one message per parent, per transaction**.

We implement spring TransactionSynchronization to get notified in a beforeCommit. We get "persistenceContext" where we check new or dirty entities, then aggregate per parent and send a notification if appropriate. A relevant code snippet:

```
@Override
void beforeCommit(boolean readOnly) {               

    def transactionObjects = ApplicationContextHolder.applicationContext.sessionFactory.currentSession.transaction.transactionContext.persistenceContext.

    List<Object> changedObjects = transactionObjects.findAll {
        it.key.isDirty() || isNewInstance(it)
    }.collect { it.key }
    // do stuff here
}
```

However, we cannot figure a built-in way to determine if an instance is new. The isDirty is only true for updates.
We tried to use the EntityEntry.previousStatus, which we thought would only be null for new instances, but a test showed that the same object can have previousStatus = null in two consequent beforeCommit calls (which is therefor not useful for our purpose).

A hack that worked for us:

- add a transient boolean to domain classes (isNewInstance)
- set it to true in "beforeInsert" event
- and clear it at the end of beforeCommit

But is it really the case that no built-in hibernate API is available?
(we cannot use instance.id == null, because it is after save() is called, and the id would be set in the persistent, but not yet committed object).

**EDIT:**

**Assumption**: Hibernate has eventually to issue a different SQL (insert vs. update) depending on if the instance is new. I understand that it generates the SQL depending on if it has an ID, then puts it immediately after in the transaction, so a null ID cannot be used as indicator.

**Question:**
But does hibernate not hold this information internally somewhere, and if so doesn't it provide a public API?

Comment: wouldn't it be enough to use afterInsert() method?

Comment: If we use afterInsert/Update/Delete, we (1) tight it to gorm (2) would have the call in both child and parent domain classes (3) would trigger one event per each change in the object tree e.g. parent change and two of its children would result in 3 events where we should only send one.

Answer (score 0):

GORM Provides methods you override to implement custom functionality when instances are inserted and updated.

Docs here: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping

Assuming Parent is a domain object, you could just implement your functionality on `beforeInsert` or `afterInsert`, which will be invoked only when the object is **newly created**.

`beforeUpdate` on the other hand would be invoked when there's an update on an existing instance.

Comment: Thanks, but we are looking for a way to do it in a beforeCommit or similar. I mentioned "a hack" where we use beforeInsert to flag an instance to be new and use that in beforeCommit, but we would like to avoid it. See my answer to  Kamil Mikolajczyk's comment on the question above.